# onclick button all products deleting instead of one product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, customer-account, delete, third-party-module

We are displaying Products in My account section & gave an option to add product to cart once user click on **Add to cart**. now we want to provide an option to **delete** the products once we click on "Delete" button.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmc]

**Edit**

After using below code, once i  click on "Delete" button, **all products are deleting** instead of one product :

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>

<?php $collections = $this->getCollection(); ?>

<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>

<div id="messages_product_view">
<?php $buttonTitle = Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')); ?>
</div>

<?php foreach ($collections as $key => $product) {

    echo $product->getName().' <br>';
     echo $product->getId().'<br />';

    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());    

?>

<?php

$itemRemoveUrl=$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/delete',array('id'=>$_product->getId(),
   Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED=>$this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl())
);
?>

<!-- delete -->


<form 
action="<?php  

Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
try
 {
$product->delete();
Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
} 
catch(Exception $e) 
{
echo "write";
}

?>" method="post">  
<div class="add-to-cart-buttons">

<button type="submit" title="Delete" class="button btn-cart" >
    <span><span>Delete</span></span>
</button>

</div>
</form>

<!-- delete code end-->


<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: How did you add code for delete button? there is no code for delete button in above code.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya i followed [link](https://sarfarazlaghari.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/magento-how-to-delete-magento-product-from-frontend-code/) & used this code  : `try {
$product->delete();
Mage::unregister(‘isSecureArea’);
} catch(Exception $e) {
echo “Product #”.$product->getId().” could not be remvoved: “.$e->getMessage();
}` , but it didt worked for me , may be i done something wrong in placing code...... please guide me on this.....

Comment: Where and how did you use above code?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya i got result `Product #195652 could not be remvoved: Cannot complete this operation from non-admin area.` seems there is no link b/w Delete button and that code, so only it didt worked, please tell me how to link to delete button....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a button that uses that variable called **$itemRemoveUrl** like a link.

**Cart remove URL**

```
$itemRemoveUrl=$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/delete',array('id'=>$_product->getId(),
   Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED=>$this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl())
);
```

**Sample:**

```
<a href="<?php echo $itemRemoveUrl ?>" class="btn btn-default"><?php echo $this->__('Delete') ?></a>
```

Comment: i tried like this : `<?php

$itemRemoveUrl=$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/delete',array('id'=>$_product->getId(),
   Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED=>$this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl())
);
?>


<button class = "button btn-cart"><?php echo $itemRemoveUrl ?></button>` is it correct ?

Comment: it's correct, you just need to add this URL to your new button.

Comment: i added url in this way : `<button class = "button btn-cart"><?php echo $itemRemoveUrl ?></button>` is this correct , please tell me what else code i need to use ?

Comment: okay , i did exactly as you said : `<?php

$itemRemoveUrl=$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/delete',array('id'=>$_product->getId(),
   Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED=>$this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl())
);
?>

<br><br>

<button class = "button btn-cart"><a href ="<?php echo $itemRemoveUrl ?>"> Button</button>` , but still onclick button, its not deleting product....

Comment: I've added a sample to implement

Comment: once i click on `Delete button` its refreshing page, but not deleting product......

Comment: yes, I checked your website and the cart page generate the same link to remove products to the cart, so I don't know why isn't working.